# No Terminal Window, Compiling With gmcs Necessary For Mono?

Tags: winforms, mono

I am compiling a Winforms app for use with Mono and using the .Net stuff built into Visual Studio 2008 for a Winforms app. Everything works fine, but I'd like to run without the terminal window opening.

Do I need to use gmcs to get this line to work:

```
-target:winexe
```

as seen [here](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Winforms)? Or can I do it with the built-in commands that Visual Studio uses for .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS, make sure the project type is set to "Windows Application" and not "Console Application" on the project properties page.

If that doesn't fix it, try using monow.exe instead of mono.exe to run the application.

Comment: Hmmm... there's no monow on OSX. I wonder if this is just a non-issue on OSX anyway? T/hanks for that answer.